# PEAR SOAP_client error

Tags: php, pear

I am getting the error

> The named parameter torrent is not in the call parameters.

for Pear SOAP_client & Torcache API

here is my code

```
$client = new SOAP_Client ( 'http://torcache.net/torcache.wsdl' );
$infoHash = $client->cacheTorrent( base64_encode( file_get_contents( 'mytorrent' ) ) );
echo ($infoHash);
```

this was linked from their API page; https://torcache.net/api

I am a little confused as how to proceed from here?
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A quick debug of the web service using PHP5's SoapClient instead of the PEAR one like so:

```
$client = new SoapClient ( 'http://torcache.net/torcache.wsdl' );
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

yieds the following:

> array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "string cacheTorrent(string $torrent)" }

Looking at their code sample what this means is that you need to pass in the base64-encoded contents of an actual .torrent file.  Based on the function signature, and previous experience with SOAP web services, I think you should try adjusting your code to:

```
$client = new SOAP_Client ( 'http://torcache.net/torcache.wsdl' ); 
echo ($infoHash);$infoHash = $client->cacheTorrent( array('torrent' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('test.torrent')) ) );
```

You will need to make sure you actually have a torrent file by the name test.torrent in the same directory as this script.